# VB.Net: MS Access database engine could not find the object

Tags: vb.net, excel-2010, ms-access-2010

I have a module in that imports Excel files into a MS Access database table.
I get: MS Access database engine could not find the object 'REPORTCONFIG'. 
The Table REPORTCONFIG does exist and it is 'picked-up' by the code because just before I import the excel I first empty the table out (which works fine).
I have made sure that the tab in my excel is that same name as the Table. (REPORTCONFIG)

This is my module:

```
Dim MyExcelFileDialogBox As New OpenFileDialog()
        If MyExcelFileDialogBox.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
            MyExcelFullFileName = MyExcelFileDialogBox.FileName
            MyExcelFile = Dir(MyExcelFileDialogBox.FileName)
            MyExcelFilePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(MyExcelFileDialogBox.FileName)
            ModuleConnection.AccessConnect()
            ModuleTables.DeleteTableContent(MyTableName)
            Dim MyExcelInsertSQL As String = "INSERT INTO [" & MyTableName & "] SELECT * FROM [Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=" & MyExcelFullFileName & "].[" & MyTableName & "];"
            Dim MyCommand As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(MyExcelInsertSQL, MyAccessConnection)
            Try
                MyCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MyCommand.Dispose()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.ToString)
            End Try
            MyAccessConnection.Close()
        End If
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried the query in MS Access by pasting into sql view? Your Excel connect string does not look right to me.

Comment: The module is working fine for another excel document which I import to a different table. What I find odd, is that if I add the data this way, then it works. <Dim MyExcelInsertSQL As String = "INSERT INTO [REPORTCONFIG] VALUES (10,1,1,'Algemene gegevens','','S','White','Blue','Arial',14,'Bold',0,15,1000,21)> So, yes you would say that the problem then lies with the excel connection string, but as I just mentioned, it is working fine for a different Excel document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a worksheet as the data source for a query, add a dollar sign (`$`) after the sheet name so it will be found.

With this simple `SELECT` query, the db engine complains it can't find `REPORTCONFIG`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM [Excel 12.0;DATABASE=C:\share\Access\MyWorkBook.xlsx;HDR=YES].[REPORTCONFIG];
```

However, when using `REPORTCONFIG$` in the `FROM` clause, the following query returns the data without error.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM [Excel 12.0;DATABASE=C:\share\Access\MyWorkBook.xlsx;HDR=YES].[REPORTCONFIG$];
```

Comment: HansUp, the $ did the trick for my document with REPORTCONFIG as tab name but now the other documents with tab name that contains underscores (rpt_bank_krediet_mg_comm_cns) are not importing anymore. Has it to do with the underscores?

Comment: HansUp, I found the problem. Problem with variable MyTableName. Thanks again for your help.